# Can we have just 2 doubleqoutes in place value for key in values.yaml of helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am using helm to deploy product in Kubernetes.

In `values.yaml` of helm chart , can we have `""` as value for a key ?
What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined `key: ""`, `{{ typeOf .Values.key }}` shows that it's a `string`

If you use it in `if/else` statement, an empty string will be evaluated as *false*

**Updated answer: What if the key is used as integer value ?**

If your `key` is defined as integer value in your values.yaml like `0: value` you can access it using [get sprig function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) like `{{ get .Values "0" }}`, because using it as `.Values.0` will generate an error

> Error: parse error at (mychart/templates/configmap.yaml:12): unexpected ".0" in operand

Comment: What if the key is used as integer value ?